# Is it possible to hide the extension icon in the extensions toolbar on sites that the extension is not active on?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

Is there a programmatic way to only show a browser extension's icon in the extension toolbar if the extension has permissions to run on the site currently being viewed in the active tab?

I'm sure at one point this was the default behaviour for Chrome / Firefox extension icons, but it seems they have changed them so all extension icons show all the time, no matter what site you are visiting.

This can be quite annoying if you have a lot of extensions installed, as the extensions toolbar gets pretty crowded.

Have i missed something here?

Comment: No, Chrome has removed such a feature and there's no alternative. Previously it was the default behavior of `page_action` - it showed an icon inside the address bar only on matching pages.

Comment: wow, that sucks